# Can I make a custom gridviewitem independent of my collectionviewsource?

Tags: xaml, gridview, windows-runtime, collectionviewsource

I have a CollectionViewSource that I use to populate my gridviewitems (black squares) and I was wondering if it would be possible to add a gridviewitem (red square) independent of my collectionviewsource. I can provide any additional info needed. Thank you for the help!

I don't have enought rep to post an image so here's a link to the image showing what I want to do:

[Image](http://imageftw.com/uploads/20130414/Untitled.png)

**Edit** - I'm doing this in the WinRT for Windows 8

Answer (score 1):

Yoyu can use `CompositeCollection` to do this sort of thing

Here is a quick example of using a `CompositeCollection`

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication10.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="325" Width="422" Name="UI">

    <Window.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="myViewSource" Source="{Binding Items, ElementName=UI}" />
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=UI}">
        <ListView>
            <ListView.ItemsSource>
                <CompositeCollection>
                    <ListViewItem Content="Hello" />
                    <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource myViewSource}}" />
                </CompositeCollection>
            </ListView.ItemsSource>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> Items
    {
        get
        {
            yield return "Item1";
            yield return "Item2";
            yield return "Item3";
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I don't think I'm able to use this in the Windows Runtime for a Windows 8 app, right?